# Issue with method

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I've got another issue. My method:

```
public StudentProfile GetFullStudentProfile(int userID)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Config.DbConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetFullUserProfile", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int));
    cmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = userID;
    StudentProfile sp = null;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

        if (reader.Read())
        {
            sp = new StudentProfile((int)reader["UserID"], (string)reader["UserName"], (string)reader["UserFamilyName"], (DateTime)reader["UserBirthDay"], (string)reader["UserTelephone"], (string)reader["UserEmail"], (DateTime)reader["UserRegDate"], (string)reader["UserComment"], (bool)reader["UserActive"]);
        }

        reader.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //lbl.Text = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    return sp;
}
```

Code in WebUserControl:

```
protected void ddlStudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CatalogAccess ca=new CatalogAccess();
    lblEmail.Visible = true;
    lblName.Visible = true;

    lblTelephone.Visible = true;
    HiddenID.Value = ddlStudents.SelectedValue;
    lblName.Text = HiddenID.Value;
    lblEmail.Text = ca.GetFullStudentProfile(ddlStudents.SelectedIndex).UserEmail;
    lblFamilyName.Visible = true;
    lblBirth.Visible = true;
    ddlStudents.Items.Clear();
    PopulateStudentsDDL();

}
```

When I run the code I am getting exception 
[image]

Do I understand right that the problem is in method GetFullStudentProfile()? If it's so, how can it be fixed?

I think the problem is:

```
StudentProfile sp = null;
```

So it says that variable sp was not filled with data in try block. Is it?

Now adding the StudentProfile.cs class listing:

```
public class StudentProfile
```

{
    public StudentProfile(int userID, string userName, string userFamilyName, DateTime userBirthDay, string userTelephone, string userEmail,DateTime userRegDate,string userComment,bool userActive)
    {
        UserID = userID;
        UserName = userName;
        UserFamilyName = userFamilyName;
        UserBirthDay = userBirthDay;
        UserTelephone = userTelephone;
        UserEmail = userEmail;
        UserRegdate = userRegDate;
        UserComment = userComment;
        UserActive = userActive;
    }

```
public int UserID
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string UserName
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string UserFamilyName
{
    get;
    set;
}

public DateTime UserBirthDay
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string UserTelephone
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string UserEmail
{
    get;
    set;
}

public DateTime UserRegdate
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string UserComment
{
    get;
    set;
}

public bool UserActive
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

}

Comment: Set a breakpoint on that line and step into the getfullstudentprofile method. That'll give you a better idea of where it is failing

Comment: I did it. How to step to getfullstudentprofile?

Comment: I took a screenshot of the IDE but forget that you can't put screenshots in comments. If you haven't modified your shortcuts, it'll be F11. If you have, click Debug -> Step Into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I made a new method:

```
public UserDetails GetUser(int userID)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Config.DbConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetFullUserProfile", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int, 4));
    cmd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = userID;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
        // Check if the query returned a record.
        if (!reader.HasRows) return null;
        // Get the first row.
        reader.Read();
        UserDetails emp = new UserDetails((int)reader["UserID"], (string)reader["UserName"], (string)reader["UserFamilyName"], (DateTime)reader["UserBirthDate"], (string)reader["UserTelephone"], (string)reader["UserEmail"], (DateTime)reader["RegDate"], (string)reader["UserComment"], (int)reader["UserActive"]);
        reader.Close();
        return emp;
    }
    catch (SqlException err)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Data error.");
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

New Class:

```
using System;

public class UserDetails
{
    public UserDetails(int userID, string userName, string userFamilyName, DateTime userBirthDate, string userTelephone, string userEmail, DateTime regDate, string userComment, int userActive)
    {
        UserID = userID;
        UserName = userName;
        UserFamilyName = userFamilyName;
        UserBirthDay = userBirthDate;
        UserTelephone = userTelephone;
        UserEmail = userEmail;
        RegDate = regDate;
        UserComment = userComment;
        userActive = UserActive;
    }

    public int UserID
    { get; set; }

    public string UserName
    { get; set; }

    public string UserFamilyName
    { get; set; }

    public DateTime UserBirthDay
    { get; set; }

    public string UserTelephone
    { get; set; }

    public string UserEmail
    { get; set; }

    public DateTime RegDate
    { get; set; }

    public string UserComment
    { get; set; }

    public int UserActive
    { get; set; }
}
```

After that in my back-code of WebUserControl:

```
UserDetails ud = ca.GetUser(24);
    //HiddenID.Value = String.Format(ud.UserID);
    lblName.Text = ud.UserName;
    lblEmail.Text = ud.UserEmail;
    lblFamilyName.Text = ud.UserFamilyName;
    lblBirth.Text=String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyy}",ud.UserBirthDay);
    lblTelephone.Text = ud.UserTelephone;
```

And got the method worked. So, this stage is ready. Thanks to everybody who helped me. Thread is closed.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is null? I bet `GetFullStudentProfile` method returns null.

Comment: Are you sure you need to specify selected index as a parameter to the GetFullStudentProfile method? Maybe it should be some student id. Anyway, you need to check result of the call for null before using  UserEmail property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what happened. The student matching passed ID is not found. I would do the following in your Client code:

```
StudentProfile sp=ca.GetFullStudentProfile(ddlStudents.SelectedIndex);
lblEmail.Text = sp != null ? sp.UserEmail : string.Empty;
```

Also i would rewrite the `GetFullStudentProfile` method's reader operation to something like this:

```
conn.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

if (reader.Read())
{
    sp = new StudentProfile((int)reader["UserID"], (string)reader["UserName"], (string)reader["UserFamilyName"], (DateTime)reader["UserBirthDay"], (string)reader["UserTelephone"], (string)reader["UserEmail"], (DateTime)reader["UserRegDate"], (string)reader["UserComment"], (bool)reader["UserActive"]);
}

reader.Close();
```

It's just a face-lift for the routine, looks nicer imho

Comment: @Dimitri Id is found. The problem is that sp not getting filled and as result returned null.

Comment: @Nathan the fact that debugger shows userID value does not mean there's a record in database matching that ID. Try this: SELECT * FROM YourUsersTable WHERE ID=2. If there's a record, then you're doing something wrong in the constructor for the StudentProfile class.

Comment: select * from dbo.Users
where UserID=3 returned me record. This statement works.

Comment: Have you tried passing userID=3 to the method above? and if so, does it return anything? If it doesn't, show us the definition of StudentProfile class with its constructor and fields/properties

Comment: @Dimitri Hello, I tried:  StudentProfile student = ca.GetFullStudentProfile(3);
        if (student != null)
        {
            lblName.Text = student.UserName;
            lblEmail.Text = student.UserEmail;
        }
        else
        {
            lblName.Text = "Null";
            lblEmail.Text = "Null";
        }. The result is Null. So it says that the problem is in StudentProfile class. I've added the listing of class in my question. Please, investigate it.

Comment: Next step would be to step through the code and see if exception is thrown. Set a breakpoint at public StudentProfile GetFullStudentProfile(int userID). As soon as it's hit, step through the code by hitting F10 and see if exception is thrown within try block. Also try removing CommandBehavior from ExecuteReader. Just use SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 0):

Also:

```
HiddenID.Value = ddlStudents.SelectedValue;
lblName.Text = HiddenID.Value;
```

I noticed in your Autos that the name was set as 1. So I think you actually are meaning to set it as:

```
lblName.Text = ddlStudents.SelectedValue;
```

I don't believe that setting the value equal to itself is going to benefit you in any way. Check your database, does the column for UserEmail allow nullables?

Also, in your database, I believe that UserID increments starting at 1, correct? SelectedIndex, I believe, starts at 0. You may need to increment the selectedvalue item by 1.

I just looked at your other question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745820/assign-list-member-to-label) and I feel I have a bit more info here.

If your database doesn't allow nullable types, I would change:

```
CatalogAccess ca=new CatalogAccess();
lblEmail.Visible = true;
lblName.Visible = true;

lblTelephone.Visible = true;
HiddenID.Value = ddlStudents.SelectedValue;
lblName.Text = HiddenID.Value;
lblEmail.Text = ca.GetFullStudentProfile(ddlStudents.SelectedIndex).UserEmail;
lblFamilyName.Visible = true;
lblBirth.Visible = true;
ddlStudents.Items.Clear();
PopulateStudentsDDL();
```

to:

```
CatalogAccess ca=new CatalogAccess();
lblEmail.Visible = true;
lblName.Visible = true;

lblTelephone.Visible = true;

// if your table's ID increments starting at 0, otherwise ddlStudents.SelectedIndex + 1
StudentProfile student = GetFullStudentProfile(ddlStudents.SelectedIndex);

if (student != null)
{
    lblName.Text = student.UserName;
    lblEmail.Text = student.UserEmail;
    //rest of the labels going here (I only see Name and Email)
}

...
```

You also may consider putting your calls making labels visible inside of the sp != null conditional so that only if a valid person displays will it actually display those labels. Otherwise keep them before it.

Otherwise I would do similar to Dimitri and say

```
lblName.Text = student.UserName != null ? student.UserName : String.Empty;
lblEmail.Text = student.UserEmail != null ? student.UserEmail : String.Empty;
// etc.
```

If nullables are possible, the student object could actually be assigned to, but the properties may not which may cause your application problems at runtime.

Comment: HiddenID.Value = ddlStudents.SelectedValue;
lblName.Text = HiddenID.Value; //here i've just checked if dropdownlist works at all.

Comment: Good Morning! I made a test. Explicitly put userID: StudentProfile student = ca.GetFullStudentProfile(2);
        if (student != null)
        {
            lblName.Text = student.UserName;
            lblEmail.Text = student.UserEmail;
            //rest of the labels going here (I only see Name and Email)
        }
        else
        {
            lblName.Text = "It's null";
        } and got Name label said "It's null". So the problem is that method doesn't get UserID

Comment: I think the problem is in GetFullStudentProfile() method. alas, I can't see it.

Comment: on this line lblEmail.Text = ca.GetFullStudentProfile(ddlStudents.SelectedIndex).UserEmail; right click on GetFullStudentProfile and Go to Definition. Set a breakpoint on your return sp line. Run it in debug. When it gets to the return sp line, hover over sp. If it is null, there is a problem in acquiring the student profile object at which case I'd set a breakpoint earlier in the GetFullStudentProfile object and just step through it until (if) it goes into your catch (Exception ex) block. If it isn't null and lists itself as a Student Profile object, click on the + sign in the tooltip that...

Comment: pops up and see what all of the properties you're going to retrieve (email, name, etc.) display. From there you'll know how your acquisition function is working for you. Also, I believe I read in another post you're using SQL Server 2005 or 2008. Is ADO a requirement or preference? Because if not, you might be interested in reading up on LINQ. After setting up the dbml, your acquiring functions are basically a matter of creating a db object, creating a sp object set to = (from c in db_object.GetFullStudentProfiles where c.UserId == userId select c).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the sp = new StudentProfile(....; now step through it. Did it hit that line? Does it complete without going to the catch if you step through that line?

Comment: @Robert http://img171.imageshack.us/i/null.png/ and http://img710.imageshack.us/i/null2.png/